# Chrome Extension JS detect http status code and refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that detects the http status code & refreshes each time the condition is met.

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ... })`

will return true if the page content has completely loaded, but is it possible to check that the status code is equal to `200` instead? & would that be quicker than waiting for the entire page to load?

Reloading the page's request using `chrome.tabs.reload()` seems to work as expected, but I combine the function with the condition it only refreshes the page once?

```
let i = 0;
while(i < 50) {
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { chrome.tabs.reload(); });
   i++;
}
```

expected outcome would be that it reloads the page 50 times? but it only reloads once.